# how to stay the button pressed

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to stay the button pressed when clicked on that button. Button's background is done using `StateList`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider using a `ToggleButton` for this kind of behaviour: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at/extend the CheckBox source code and use that as a starting point?